# Как открывать все полученные url в webview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Есть приложение которое работает с wordpress, контент открывается через webview. И вот когда я нажимаю на ссылку в webview она открывается во внешнем браузере, а мне надо чтоб открывалась внутри webview

```
  WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    String html_data = "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> ";
    html_data += post.content;
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings();
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadData(html_data, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

    final String finalHtml_data = html_data;
    webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
        }
    });
```

Вот что выдает в логе

{
    2018-11-01 11:28:13.075 20956-20956/com.mensphysics.scuma I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:348221768 intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://aff.plussy.ru/... }
2018-11-01 11:28:13.087 27808-30266/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://aff.plussy.ru/... cmp=com.android.browser/.LauncherActivity} from uid 11700 on display 0
2018-11-01 11:28:13.099 467-2721/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2018-11-01 11:28:13.099 27808-30266/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
2018-11-01 11:28:13.110 20956-22619/com.mensphysics.scuma V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 3998
2018-11-01 11:28:13.111 20956-22619/com.mensphysics.scuma V/FA: Activity paused, time: 950211684
2018-11-01 11:28:13.115 20956-22619/com.mensphysics.scuma D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=3998, _sc=ActivityPostDetails, _si=-4015450635979384408}]
}

Comment: `webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` - здесь `WebViewClient` стандартный класс или Ваш кастомный? Если первое попробуйте сделать `Build->Rebuild Project` и проверить по новой. Если второе - покажите его код.

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Comment: @woesss, думаю, это можно в ответ написать)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView vw = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
vw.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```